# Как заменить страндартную ошибку MySQL на свой текст?

Tags: php

Как заменить страндартную ошибку MySQL на свой текст. После отправки формы у меня проверяется уникальность логина, если он не уникален, то выдаст ошибку "Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'login'", а нужно чтобы он выдавал что-то типа "Логин уже занят выберите другой..."

Comment: сделайте мэпинг ошибок. вот тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752745/create-custom-error-message-mysql  пример как это сделать средствами sp в mysql. можно аналогично сделать и на пехепе.

Answer (score 3):

Последнее, что надо делать - отображать ошибки БД (или даже вашего кода) конечному пользователю.

Исходный текст ошибки вы можете хранить у себя в логах, но пользователю вы всегда должны показывать только те ошибки, которые вы для него сформировали. Например, если при выполнении запроса произошла какая-либо ошибка, можно всегда написать: *"Возникла непредвиденная ошибка, попробуйте повторить позже или свяжитесь с техподдержкой"*

Если вы хотите отображать различные текстовки на разные ошибки, то достаточно посмотреть на значение [mysqli_errno](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.errno.php) и по коду ошибки генерировать свое сообщение.

---

Конкретно в вашем же случае, проверку на уникальность стоило выполнить еще до того, как был выполнен запрос. Это называется валидацией.

Т.е. пользователь вводит необходимые данные, сабмитит форму, а вы проверяете данные формы на валидность (или правильность). В том числе, проверяете, что введенный логин ни кем не занят.

Таким образом, если логин уже занят, вы будете знать об этом и сможете сообщить об этом пользователю.

Конечно, может возникнуть ситуация, когда уникальность логина прошла проверку, но сразу после этого логин был использован кем-то другим. Тогда выполнение запроса закончится ошибкой. Но т.к. такая ситуация будет происходить очень-и-очень редко, то на нее можно отвечать стандартным *"возникла ошибка, повторите попытку"*.